# Are elliptic curves infinite loop spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Is the group action on an elliptic curve reflecting the fact that it is a space with with transfers?

Through the recognition principle

$$\mathrm{Mon}_{\mathbb{E}_\infty}(\mathrm{Spc})^{gp}\simeq \mathrm{Sp}_{\geq0}\subset \mathrm{Sp}=\:\text{cohomology theories}$$

there must be a cohomology theory for every elliptic curve. Is this elliptic cohomology developed by Lurie?

Comment: Crossposted from Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374022/are-elliptic-curves-infinite-loop-spaces. (In the future, please note MSE crossposts in the original question to avoid duplication of effort.)

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is appropriate for MO, but here is a quick answer: This is not elliptic cohomology, actually, this is a sum of two copies of ordinary singular cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ (with an index shift by $1$). The reason is that the homotopy type of an elliptic curve is $S^1\times S^1$, and $S^1$ is the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$.

Comment: Note that it's *grouplike* $\mathbb E_\infty$ spaces that are equivalent to connective spectra.